# Wordpress Code to show single category list in sidebar not including current month

Tags: wordpress, archive

I have found and tweaked some code to show a single category in monthly listings for wordpress in the sidebar. I have one issue though, I do not want it to show the current month. Not sure how to tweak it.

```
<?php
                global $wpdb, $wp_locale;
                $query = "select YEAR(post_date) AS <code>year</code>, MONTH(post_date) AS <code>month</code>, count(ID) as posts from $wpdb->posts,  $wpdb->term_taxonomy, $wpdb->term_relationships
                    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
                    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 9
                    AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
                    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
                 GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC";
                 $arcresults = $wpdb->get_results($query);
                foreach ($arcresults as $arcresult):
                $text = sprintf(__('%1$s %2$d'), $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month), $arcresult->year);?>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/<?php echo $arcresult->year; ?>/<?php echo str_pad($arcresult->month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>/<?php echo "?cat=9";  ?>"><?php echo $text;  ?> </li>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [Date_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) objects. You can pass a Date_Query to WP_Query which will filter out the latest month when given the correct parameters.

Using the WP_Query object is far more efficient (for the developer) than building complex SQL queries.